# How to have a field which is both derived and multivalued?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am designing an ERM model for my project and have a field that is both multivalued and derived. I can't find any resource online how to represent such a field in an ERM diagram.

Comment: In entity-relationship models you achieve multivalued field through one-to-many or many-to-many relationship for example. To make it derived i think you should do a view on top of the data you want to derive the field from